# Spring MVC, append a node to an existing XML-file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm working on a login with my Spring MVC application. I created a file in /WEB-INF/content/users.xml where I save the users. It looks like this:

```
<user>
    <username>user1</username>
    <password>e38ad214943daad1d64c102faec29de4afe9da3d</password>
    <uuid>213214</uuid>
</user>
```

I have two controllers, one handling the login (reading the file) and one for the registration process (appending a node to the file). Everything seems to work but my controller is not writing to that file. I guess a copy or some kind of stream is being created by Tomcat and loaded upon starting but no information is written to the actual file. My code so far looks like this.

```
servletContextResource = new ServletContextResource(servletContext,"/WEB-INF/content/users.xml");
userXML = servletContextResource.getFile();
```

I can read the file this way. I tried the following to write to the same file

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(userXML);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Everything worked so far but there was no data written to the file, Tomcat was working on a copy (I guess).

I later on tried the following.

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
String filePath = servletContextResource.getPathWithinContext();
File newXML = new File (filePath);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(newXML);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

and got a FileNotFound-Exception. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider WEB-INF as read-only. It's bundled inside your deployed war file. Use a file OUTSIDE of the webapp, so that each redeploy doesn't make you lose all the data written in the file. Or better, use a database.

Comment: I've been thinking about using a database but in my opinion it's not worth it. This project will never go live. It's just a simple application for a presentation. The prof told me to use a simple XML file. But thank you for the answer